# Citation format for Editor's Response

Tags: citation-style

I have a question about citation format.

I would like to cite the comments by the editor at the beginning of a "Letters to the editor" [section](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690589?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) from Mathematics Magazine's October 1995 issue.

(Not any of the letters themselves. The comments by the editor that precede the letters.)

What's the format? Most importantly, what are the author and title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor appears to have been a [Martha Siegel](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/mathematics-magazine/editors-of-mathematics-magazine), but I think the simplest solution in your case is to go the [table of contents](https://www.jstor.org/stable/i326785?refreqid=excelsior%3A23bb832f461a0d0eee987a945591a770) of that issue, and click ["Cite this item"](https://www.jstor.org/citation/info/10.2307/2690589), which yields citations like

> Mixon, Bill, Steven J. Brams, D. Marc Kilgour, Robert Mandl, David L. Farnsworth, and David M. Bloom. "News and Letters." Mathematics Magazine 68, no. 4 (1995): 322-24. http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690589.

for the news and letters section. A three page document is short enough that you don't really need to be more specific than that. Still, if you want you can make it clear in the text that you're only citing the editor's introduction to the section. A less standard solution would be adding something to that effect in brackets in the reference list, e.g. "[Editor's introduction]".